React Native keep location tracking and websocket active when app is on background
i have a project in react native that sends via websocket real-time coordinates via a node backend server and after im receiving them from a react frontend page. The problem i have is that when the app is in background the websocket wont work also location tracking. Any ideas?
Backend Code:
// Import the 'ws' (WebSocket) module
const WebSocket = require('ws');

// Create a new WebSocket server instance, listening on port 8080
const wss = new WebSocket.Server({ port: process.env.PORT || 8080 });

// Initialize an array to store coordinates
const coordinates = [];

// Event listener for when a client connects to the server
wss.on('connection', function connection(ws) {
  console.log('A new client connected');

  // Event listener for when a message is received from a client
  ws.on('message', function incoming(message) {
    console.log('Received: %s', message);

    // Parse the incoming message (assuming it's JSON)
    try {
      const data = JSON.parse(message);
      // Push the coordinates to the array
      coordinates.push(data);
      
      // Broadcast the message to all connected clients
      wss.clients.forEach(function each(client) {
        if (client !== ws && client.readyState === WebSocket.OPEN) {
          // Send the message to all clients except the sender
          client.send(JSON.stringify(data));
        }
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error parsing message:', error);
    }
  });

  // Event listener for when the connection is closed
  ws.on('close', function close() {
    console.log('Client disconnected');
  });

  console.log('WebSocket server listening on port 8080');
});

and React Native code:
 const wsRef = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    // Establish WebSocket connection
    wsRef.current = new WebSocket('wss://websocketa-52220f631af2.herokuapp.com/');

    // Event handler for when WebSocket connection is open
    wsRef.current.onopen = () => {
      console.log('WebSocket connected');
    };

    // Event handler for when WebSocket receives a message
    wsRef.current.onmessage = (event) => {
      console.log('Received message:', event.data);
    };

    // Event handler for WebSocket errors
    wsRef.current.onerror = (error) => {
      console.error('WebSocket error:', error);
    };

    // Clean up WebSocket connection on component unmount
    return () => {
      wsRef.current.close();
    };
  }, []);

  // Function to send location data to the server
  const sendLocationToServer = (latitude, longitude) => {
    if (wsRef.current) {
      wsRef.current.send(JSON.stringify({ latitude, longitude }));
    }
  };

  // Request permission to access location
  const handleConnectButtonPress = () => {
    // Run getCurrentPosition immediately
    getCurrentPosition();
    // Run getCurrentPosition every 5 seconds
    setInterval(getCurrentPosition, 5000);
    showLocationServiceNotification();

  };
  // Get the current position
  const getCurrentPosition = () => {
    Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
      position => {
        const { latitude, longitude } = position.coords;
        console.log('Latitude:', latitude);
        console.log('Longitude:', longitude);
        // Send location data to the server
        sendLocationToServer(latitude, longitude);
      },
      error => {
        console.log('Error getting location:', error);
      },
      { enableHighAccuracy: true, timeout: 15000, maximumAge: 10000 }
    );
  };

  const showLocationServiceNotification = () => {
    PushNotification.localNotification({
      channelId: 'location-service-channel',
      title: 'Location Service',
      message: 'Location service is running in the background.',
    });
  };
    // Request permission to access location

  useEffect(() => {
    Geolocation.requestAuthorization();
  }, []);


and the manifest:

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACTIVITY_RECOGNITION" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />


I tried to install some libraries like react-native-geolocation but couldn't find a solution..
